# SSMS KeyBoard Shortcut for DoubleClick in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Is there a keyboard shortcut for the mouse equivalent of doubleclicking and it highlight just the word within parentheses or quotes etc. (For Example: (TestColumn)  and it highlight TestColumn ) in SSMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "double-click" shortcut. However, there is somthing that will get you close: `[Ctrl]-[Arrow Left]` gets you to the beginning of the current word. `[Ctrl]-[Shift]-[Arrow Right]` then highlights the current word.

There are two caveats:

1. If you start on the first letter `[Ctrl]-[Arrow Left]` will jump to the beginning of the previous word
2. if the first character after the word is a space it will get selected as well.